# A dice is thrown five times.Find the probability of getting only $1.$

Tags: probability

A dice is thrown five times.Find the probability of getting only $1.$

---

Out of five throws,$1XXXX,X1XXX,XX1XX,XXX1X,XXXX1,$where $X$ denotes numbers other than $1.$So the probability of getting only $1$ is $5\times(\frac{1}{6})(\frac{5}{6})^4$
But the answer given in my book is $5\times (\frac{1}{6})^5$,I dont know where i am wrong.

Comment: What does "getting only $1$" mean?

Comment: Just this statement is given in the question.

Comment: Well, I think most (or all) people would interpret that as getting $1,1,1,1,1$ so the answer is $\left( \frac 16 \right)^5$.

Comment: Yes, @lulu is correct. You have found the probability of getting: *only one $1$*, whereas the question asks for the probability of rolling *only $1$s*.

Comment: But then the answer in the book is incorrect, so the confusion of the OP is justified.

Comment: To be sure, I don't see any interpretation of the question that leads to $5\times \left( \frac 16 \right)^5$.

Comment: Neither do I. The answer in the book is most probably wrong.

Comment: Or perhaps the question is just that badly misquoted. Surely it is not quoted verbatim: what editor lets a book be published with the phrase "a dice"?

Comment: @DavidK - 'dice' is now accepted as both a valid plural OR singular form. It's stupid and it still sounds weird, but that's what happens when enough people use horrible grammar for long enough.

Comment: @SeanHenderson Well, I wouldn't go around editing stackexchange posts to "fix" it, but I though that "acceptable in a math textbook" was still a different standard than "acceptable in general usage." OTOH, if it's from a problem set that some instructor whipped up then I guess all bets are off! So I withdraw the comment about a book, while still inquiring about the accuracy of the transcription of this question.

Answer (score 1):

You have correctly calculated the probability of getting exactly one $1$.  Note there are two "one"s in the sentence, which is different from the question you asked.  I would read "getting only $1$" as rolling $1,1,1,1,1$, which has a probability of $(\frac 16)^5$.  I can't think of any way to read the question to get $5(\frac 16)^5$