# What is the probability that this event is actually true?

Tags: probability

A man speaks truth 3 times out of 5.He says that in tossing 6 coins,two tails appear.What is the probability that this event is actually true?

---

Let $E_1$ be the event he speaks truth and $E_2$ be the event he speaks a lie.
$P(E_1)=\frac{3}{5},P(E_2)=\frac{2}{5}$
Let $A$ be the event that $2$ tails appear.
We need to find $P(E_1/A)=\frac{P(E_1).P(A/E_1)}{P(E_1).P(A/E_1)+P(E_2).P(A/E_2)}$
$P(A/E_1)=6C2\times(\frac{1}{2})^6=\frac{15}{64}$,What will be $P(A/E_2)?$
The answer for probability that this event is actually true is $\frac{115}{288}$

Comment: Could you give more precisions to your question? It is written as if he was saying that the overall result was 2 tails out of 6 coins. If this is his only statement, the probability is $3/5$. But I guess that 2 tails is the result of the compilation of each toss, as reported independantely by the man? Is that so?

Comment: As with [your prior question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2612034/a-dice-is-thrown-five-times-find-the-probability-of-getting-only-1) this question is poorly phrased.  Do you mean "exactly two" or "at least two"?  Also...what have you tried?  This site doesn't exist to do your homework for you.

Comment: Hint:  Assuming (well, guessing) that you meant "exactly two" then there are two scenarios in which the man says what he says.  Either exactly two $T$ came up AND he told the truth or something other than exactly two $T$ came up AND he lied.

Comment: I have edited my answer.

Comment: Are you asking this man "How many tails were there?", or "Did you get two tails?" In the case of the former, he might have three tails, and lie and say he got four, or he could lie and say he got two (let's not get into the possibility that he could say "I got 53").

Comment: One could argue that the probability is $1,$ or practically $1.$ There are an infinite number of lies (or at least unimaginably many) that the man could have told if he were lying (for example, "I am ten meters tall"); the probability that he would choose the particular lie "three are two tails" is therefore vanishingly small for every other actual number of tails, and Bayes' Theorem gives $1$ as the probability of two tails. (I don't intend this argument seriously; I merely mean to say the problem is ill-posed.)

Comment: @DavidK  I was just writing something along those lines.   I'd say the only sensible way to read the question is to imagine that you asked the man "did two tails come up?"  and he replied yes.

Comment: @lulu Another interpretation is that you ask "how many tails?" and if he lies, he chooses one of the five plausible false answers with equal probability.

Comment: Does he speak six times, two times, or once?

Answer (score 1):

The application of Bayes's Theorem in the question is incorrect. The conditional probability $P(E_1\mid A)$ is the probability that the man says two tails, given that there were two tails. What we want is the probability that there are two tails given that the man said there were two tails.

I find it next to useless to give names to events such as "the man lies" in problems like this. 
In fact, assuming the man lies $\frac35$ of the time regardless of what actually happens, $P(A\mid E_1) = P(A\mid E_2) = P(A)$. And *without* that assumption, it is possible that the man always tells the truth when there are two tails in six coin tosses, and lies in more than $\frac35$ of all other cases to come to a total probability of $\frac35$ to lie, so without further information we could not conclude anything at all.

A better formulation is to define $B$ as the event that the man says there are two tails. Then the answer is $P(A\mid B)$ where
$$
P(A\mid B) = \frac{P(B\cap A)}{P(B\cap A) + P(B\cap A^\complement)}
= \frac{P(B\mid A)P(A)}{P(B\mid A)P(A) 
     + P(B\mid A^\complement)P(A^\complement)}.
$$

We still have to assume the man's decision to lie is independent of what happened, so $P(B\mid A) = \frac35.$
As you already found, $P(A) = \frac{15}{64},$
so $P(A^\complement) = \frac{49}{64}.$

We just need to know the value of $P(B\mid A^\complement)$
in order to apply the formula.
That's where creative interpretation of the problem statement comes in.
If the actual train of events was six coins were tossed,
we asked the man if there were exactly two tails, and he said "yes,"
then $P(B\mid A^\complement) = \frac25.$
If instead we had asked the man how many tails occurred and he said "two,"
$P(B\mid A^\complement)$ depends on the answers to questions such as,
"How likely is it that the man would have said 'four' rather than 'two' if there had been exactly three tails and he lied?"
And if the man said there were two tails without any prompting,
how do we know the probability that he would have said
*that particular lie* in the event of three tails?

I believe the usual interpretation of problems like this is the first one:
the man is (at least in effect) simply answering "yes" or "no" to the question whether there were two tails;
"two" is the only possible lie he can tell when there are more or fewer than  two tails.
I also think this is a stupid way to frame a problem;
if that is the intent, then the writer should *state explicitly in the problem statement* that the man is answering a yes/no question.